# disable a function on state change

Tags: reactjs

i want to disable/enable a function, depends on state.

the problem is, i have this function that create some css effect,
which works only in .

it takes the DIV that classNamed "glass" and does some stuff.

this div appears only in , but NOT on Homepage2.
so what happens is when i change state to view Homepage2, i get this:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null.

so im guessing i need to stop the function?

the App

```
function App() {
const Theme = useSelector(state => state.ThemeReducer);
return (
<div className="App">
  {Theme === "Theme1" &&
  <Homepage />
  }
  {Theme === "Theme2" &&
  <Homepage2 />
  }
 </div>
 );
 }
```

Homepage

```
const Homepage1 () => {
//this is the function i want to stop/start depends on state
document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e){
const glass = document.querySelector(".glass");
glass.style.left = e.offsetX + "px";
glass.style.top = e.offsetY + "px";
  // dont get too much into this function its not importent

return(
   <div className="glass" />
   <h1>this is HOMEPAGE 1</h1>
   <button>this button changing theme with redux</button>
)
```

hompage 2

```
const Homepage2 = () => (
<div> homepage 2 </div>
<button>this button changing theme with redux</button>
)
```

Comment: `if (glass) {}` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exit the `mousemove` handler if `glass` is `null` then simply check that condition:

```
if (!glass) {
  return;
}
```

Comment: sorry guys i dont get it ): where should i put it? before this function? inside? after?

Comment: @barakooren: Well, the purpose here is to check whether `glass` was defined with a value before you use it.  So you'd put this anywhere between where `glass` is defined and where it's used.  So probably right after the `const glass ...` line.